# What's the formula for this series for $\pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi, continued-fractions

These continued fractions for $\pi$ were given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#.CF.80),

$$\small
\pi = \cfrac{4} {1+\cfrac{1^2} {2+\cfrac{3^2} {2+\cfrac{5^2} {2+\ddots}}}}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4(-1)^n}{2n+1} 
= \frac{4}{1} - \frac{4}{3} + \frac{4}{5} - \frac{4}{7} + \cdots\tag1
$$

$$\small
\pi = 3 + \cfrac{1^2} {6+\cfrac{3^2} {6+\cfrac{5^2} {6+\ddots}}}
= 3 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n} {n (n+1) (2n+1)} 
= 3 + \frac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3} - \frac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 5} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 4\cdot 7} - \cdots\tag2
$$

$$\small
\pi = \cfrac{4} {1+\cfrac{1^2} {3+\cfrac{2^2} {5+\cfrac{3^2} {7+\ddots}}}}
= 4 - 1 + \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{34} + \frac {16}{3145} - \frac{4}{4551} + \frac{1}{6601} - \frac{1}{38341} + \cdots\tag3$$

Unfortunately, the third one didn't include a closed-form for the series. (I tried the OEIS using the denominators, but no hits.)

> **Q.** What's the series formula for $(3)$?

Comment: Why don't you use the Euler formula to find the series yourself? I assume you know of that formula. See "Euler's formula in modern notation" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula

Comment: When you look at the prime factorization of the denominators, you feel little hope of a similarly simple formula.

Comment: @peter.petrov: I don't think that's what they used.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yes, I was in fact looking at the denominator's prime factorizations too.

Comment: Ah, you mean it's another but equivalent series (with same sum). Hm...

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because then the equals sign between the continued fraction and the series would be incorrect, no? How should we understand it? Normally it's understood as "the n-th convergent of the continued fraction is equal to the n-th partial sum of the series", no?

Comment: The ratios of successive terms are very roughly $-1/6$. More than probably, no closed formula is known, except of Ramanujan.

Comment: @peter.petrov: If they used the Euler formula, the denominators would have smaller primes dividing them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The third one should be obtained from [$4.1.40$ in A&S p.68](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_68.htm) using $z:=ix$ (from Euler I think not sure) :

$$-2\,i\,\log\frac{1+ix}{1-ix} = \cfrac{4x} {1+\cfrac{(1x)^2} {3+\cfrac{(2x)^2} {5+\cfrac{(3x)^2} {7+\ddots}}}}
$$
Except that the expansion of the function at $x=1$ is simply your expansion for $(1)$.

Some neat variants :

$$\varphi(x):=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{x+t}dt= \cfrac{1} {x+1-\cfrac{1^2} {x+3-\cfrac{2^2} {x+5-\cfrac{3^2} {x+7-\ddots}}}}$$
$$\text{the previous one was better for large $x$...}$$
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}\left(1+\frac tn\right)^n\,dt=1+ \cfrac{n} {1+\cfrac{1(n-1)} {3+\cfrac{2(n-2)} {5+\cfrac{3(n-3)} {7+\ddots}}}}$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac 2{(x+2k+1)^2}= \cfrac{1} {x+\cfrac{1^4} {3x+\cfrac{2^4} {5x+\cfrac{3^4} {7x+\ddots}}}}$$
$$\text{and thus $\dfrac{\zeta(2)}2$ for $x=1$ (Stieltjes)}$$

$$\text{The last one was obtained after division by $n$ at the limit $n=0$ :}$$
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{t^{x-n}-t^{x+n}}{1-t^2}dx&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac 1{x-n+2k+1}-\frac 1{x+n+2k+1}\\
&=\cfrac{n} {x+\cfrac{1^2(1^2-n^2)} {3x+\cfrac{2^2(2^2-n^2)} {5x+\cfrac{3^2(3^2-n^2)} {7x+\ddots}}}}\\
\end{align}$$

Your continued fraction appears too in a neat and recent book by Borwein, van der Poorten, Shallit, Zudilin ["Neverending Fractions: An Introduction to Continued Fractions"](http://books.google.com/books?id=kzWzAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA169) at the end of the pages $167-169$ reproduced for convenience here (hoping there is no problem with that...) :

[image: p167]
[image: p168]
[image: p169]

Comment: Hm, interesting. If we let $x=iy$ in your answer, what we get is, $$-2\log\frac{1-y}{1+y} = \cfrac{4y} {1-\cfrac{(1y)^2} {3-\cfrac{(2y)^2} {5-\cfrac{(3y)^2} {7-\ddots}}}}$$ What I know is the similar cfrac,  $$2\log\frac{y+1}{y-1} = \cfrac{4} {y-\cfrac{1^2} {3y-\cfrac{2^2} {5y-\cfrac{3^2} {7y-\ddots}}}}
$$ A third variant is given in this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula#The_natural_logarithm), though it involves squares of odd numbers.

Comment: Those variants can be explained by the cfrac found [here](http://www.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739431/conjectured-general-continued-fraction-for-the-quotient-of-gamma-functions)

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{k}\right)=\cfrac{z}{k+\cfrac{(z)^2}{3k+\cfrac{(2z)^2}{5k+\cfrac{(3z)^2}{7k+\cfrac{(4z)^2}{9k+\ddots}}}}}$$

Answer (score 6):

Given the symmetric continued fraction found in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739431/conjectured-general-continued-fraction-for-the-quotient-of-gamma-functions)

$$\frac{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{a+3b}{4(a+b)}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3a+b}{4(a+b)}\right)}{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{3a+5b}{4(a+b)}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5a+3b}{4(a+b)}\right)}=\cfrac{4(a+b)}{a+b+\cfrac{(2a)(2b)} {3(a+b)+\cfrac{(3a+b)(a+3b)}{5(a+b)+\cfrac{(4a+2b)(2a+4b)}{7(a+b)+\ddots}}}}$$

Your continued fraction $(3)$ is a special case when $a=b=1$.

Moreover ,it has a beautiful q-analogue

$$\begin{aligned}\Big(\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n(n+1)}\Big)^2 =\cfrac{1}{1-q+\cfrac{q(1-q)^2}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^2(1-q^2)^2}{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^3(1-q^3)^2}{1-q^7+\ddots}}}}\end{aligned}$$ found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387636/ramanujan-theta-function-and-its-continued-fraction) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1389966/a-theta-function-around-its-natural-boundary/1390640#1390640).

Comment: That's very interesting, Nicco. (However, you have to fix your link. To redirects to an edit page.)

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention ,Tito and I'm glad that you find it interesting .